# use different xib items with the same UIViewController class

Tags: ios, xib

I have created a .xib file containing a `UITabBar` with 5 `UITabBarItems` inside. I would like 4 of the 5 tabs to link to the same `UIViewController` class since they have the exact same interface (only the data differentiate their looks).

Therefore it makes sense for me to instantiate my `UIViewController` 4 times, once per tab bar item. And then link each one of the `UITabBarItems` of the .xib with one instance of my `UIViewController`.

But I cannot figure out a way to take a reference of my xib tab bar items in my `UIViewController` and send the setTabBarItem message. How could I achieve that ? I was trying somehow to pass the .xib tab bar items on init (overwriting the init) but I didn't manage to reference them. I instantiate the controllers in the `AppDelegate` after the self.window stuff.

(If I say something weird here, not making sense with the usual iOS programming conventions, please let me know)

Comment: You are expected to use only one view controller per tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITabBarController` for this , not sure what you exactly want to do with the same `UIViewController` but `UITabbarController` will definitely work;

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];

ViewController *viewController1  = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController1"];
ViewController2 *viewController2  = [[ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2"];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,viewController1,viewController1,viewController1,viewController2,nil];

self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. In the xib file of the tabBarController I have tab bar items ofc. How do I link each tab bar item of the xib file with viewController1 ?

Comment: You simply drag the view controller in the left list onto the UITabBarController under the UITabbar object.